# Hightcharts present values by date from database

Tags: laravel, highcharts

I am new to Highcharts so I'm stacked here :(

In my database I have link click statistics. For example

```
id    link_id   referrer        ip_addr   created_at
1     3         facebook.com    0.0.0.0   2014-05-12 02:32:37
...
```

How can I display on chart how many links was clicked separated by days

So I need to have on X-Axys for example 12.05.2014. and on Y-Axys sum of rows from table with that date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have script (i.e in php) which get data from database and parse data (dates and value) to the correct value (time should be timestamp). Then use json_encode() to return json and get it in the javascript (via $.getJSON). After it use in the highcharts.

Comment: But I can't find the way how to parse that, I am using PHP but how to group by date and sum the number of clicks?